# Capistrano, Git, and Rails. (Reset hard head)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

So I had been (stupidly) making changes directly on the live server instead of making them on my local machine and deploying them. This messed up my deployment. So now I was to do "git reset --hard".

On my remote server I have a project.git directory (for the repository... which is bare btw) and a project directory (for my actual application).

But when I try to run "git reset --hard" it tells me I'm not on a working tree. If I go into config and change bare to false... it says the same thing.

Ideas?

Comment: as I know running again `cap deploy` from your computer will overwrite the release you have and this way you'll have the app on your server at the same state as on your local computer.

Comment: That's  the problem: That hasn't been happening. Because I was making edits right on the main server (instead of doing it locally then deploying) it screwed up the branch somehow. So Cap deploy hasn't been updating all the files.

Comment: Ok, why don't you just delete the folder of your app on the server, and deploy again as it would be from zero, the database and gems stays intact, you just move over the code as you would deploy first time.

Comment: I might delete all those useless "releases" eventually... but for now I was too worried about the version tracking. In fact I won't even have to worry about it because I'll be switching severs anyway. So the next time I do a deploy it should just "work".

Comment: "I was too worried about the version tracking" - you don't have to, it will deploy the new app with all git history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution. :)

First I did a `git reset --hard` on the local server (since the remote server is just a bare repository.)

Then I did a `git commit -a` which told me there were no changes but that there were untracked files.

So I did a `git add .` to add all the files that weren't being tracked.

Finally I ran `git commit -a` again and `git push`.

This updated my repository with all the new files and then `cap deploy` functioned as expected.